# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] doesn't work when #text at the end of url

Tags: php

I know $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] works in getting the current page's url, but it leaves out the #post at the end of the url.  I like to use the #blah at the end to make the page scroll to a certain point. Example:

```
index.php#answer
```

using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] just returns:

```
index.php
```

How can I make it read the #answer at the end as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URL hashes are never sent to the server. So it's impossible to retrieve it using PHP or any other server-side language.

To achieve the scrolling, give the element you want to scroll to `id="answer"` - then the browser will jump to it automatically. In case you want to perform smooth scrolling using JavaScript, you can access the hash via `location.hash` - there are some nice jQuery plugins available which will take care of scrolling smoothly to a specified element.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I make PHP go to a certain spot on the page?  I don't know the whole code, just an idea

Comment: PHP cannot "go to a certain spot". It runs on the server so it just sends HTML back to the browser. If you want to pass data to the PHP script, use GET arguments, i.e. `foo.php?whatever=something` and then access them using `$_GET['whatever']` in your PHP script.

Comment: You need to add an ID attribute to a tag like <div id="answer"> and a link to that tag like, "<a href="#answer">Go to Answer</a>.  If you load a webpage with the hash in it, it will automatically go to <div id="answer"> section.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work since hashes won't be sent to the server it is for on-page anchoring.

You can only use the `PATH_INFO` and the `QUERY_STRING` or the `REQUEST_URI` which is the combination of the two mentioned before. QUERY_STRING is the part after an optional `?` in the URI.

You can access that hash from javascript and send it through AJAX if you really want to.